# match a part of a string and print the whole string

Tags: awk, sed

A command on my Ubuntu system prints the following output and I'm saving the output into a variable $problem_dbs:

```
tacservices/e43ccb05-5b0a-4403-950b-9c91ed3f3694 unresponsive agent z1 10.213.197.77 tac-nightly-test tacservices/54be8202-2304-462e-8574-1aef379160d9 failing z1 10.213.204.228 tac-Trip-test
```

I want to search and print the string that starts with 'tac-*':

```
tac-nightly-test
tac-Trip-test
```

I've tried:

```
echo $problem_dbs | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(tac-\)/\1/p'
```

but it only prints `tac-Trip-test`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Similar: [Find all strings which match the pattern](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/603618)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command means "don't print anything (`-n`) unless you can substitute everything from the beginning of the line until the last occurrence of `tac-` with itself". So you are removing everything before the last `tac-` and then printing, so you only get `tac-Trip-test`.

Since `sed` doesn't do "non-greedy" matches, this means that `.*` will always match the longest possible string. Other tools, however, can do non-greedy matching:

1. GNU `grep`

   ```
   $ echo "$problem_dbs" | grep -oP '(^|\s)\Ktac-\S+'
   tac-nightly-test
   tac-Trip-test
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   $ echo "$problem_dbs" | perl -lane 'print join "\n",grep{/^tac-\S+/}@F'
   tac-nightly-test
   tac-Trip-test
   ```
3. various

   ```
   $ echo "$problem_dbs" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '^tac-'
   tac-nightly-test
   tac-Trip-test
   ```

Comment: "coreutils" is a bit misleading there. If that refers to GNU coreutils, note that there's no `grep` in there, and it's likely not the `echo` from GNU coreutils that will be invoked as most shells have it builtin. Maybe you meant standard POSIX utilities (though you can't use `echo` on arbitrary text POSIXly (or not)), `printf` should be used instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair enough. I chickened out and just called it "various" :)

Answer (score 5):

If your awk version supports input that doesn't have a terminating newline (which AFAIK all do) then all you need is:

```
printf '%s' "$problem_dbs" | awk -v RS=' ' '/^tac-/'
tac-nightly-test
tac-Trip-test
```

Otherwise with GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `\s`:

```
awk -v RS='\\s' '/^tac-/'
```

or with any awk (assuming you have a single line of input as shown in your question and never have multi-line input with a `tac-` string at the end of one line and then immediately again at the start of the next line):

```
awk -v RS=' ' '{sub(/\n/,"")} /^tac-/'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "$problem_dbs" | awk '
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i ~ /^tac-/)
            print $(i)
}'
tac-nightly-test
tac-Trip-test
```